# Bootstrap page layout not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a simple SPA using bootstrap. I am having difficulty getting the sections of the UI to "line up" correctly.

Here is my HTML & CSS so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Treeview styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tree.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        body{
        padding: 3px;
        }        
        .dropbtn {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .dropdown {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          min-width: 160px;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a {
          color: black;
          padding-left: 5px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
          background-color: #3e8e41;
        }

        hr.menu-seperator { 
            margin: 3px 0px;
        }

        /* display area */
        #display-area {
            border: 1px solid grey; min-height: 400px;
        }

        /* Icon bar Styling */
        .icon-bar {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #555;
            overflow: auto;
            }

            .icon-bar a {
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
            color: white;
            font-size: 12px;
            }

            .icon-bar a:hover {
                background-color: #000;
            }

            .active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
            }        
    </style>    

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">File</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a id="menu-item1" href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Menu Item 1</a>
                        <a id="menu-item2" href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Menu Item 2</a>
                        <a id="menu-item3" href="#" class="menu-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Menu Item 3</a>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="icon-bar">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a> 
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i></a> 
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a> 
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a> 
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="menu-seperator"/>
        <div id="display-area" class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                        <div class="col-sm-11" id="target"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 panel">
                            <h4>Control</h4>
                            <div class="score">
                                <div class="dataScore"></div>
                                <div class="priceScore"></div>
                            </div>
                        
                            <div class="circleDrawn">Count: 0</div>
                            <button class="reset">Reset</button>
                            <button class="toggleDraw">Draw</button>
                            <button class="saveData">Save</button>
                            <button class="plotCircles">Plot</button>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="delete" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="confirm">Confirm</div>
                            <div class="action">
                                <div class="yes">Yes</div>
                                <div class="no">No</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>  
    </div>

        <!-- Modal forms -->
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="exampleModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 id="modal-title" class="modal-title">Title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="tree" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button id="btn-just-do-it" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Open</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here are the issues on the page:

1. I want the block in green surrounding the menu 'File' to be the same height as the navbar shown on the right, and the text 'File' to be vertically centered within that block in green. Using `height: 100%;` on the element has no effect.
2. I want the icons in the div.icon-bar to be floated right, but if I apply `float: right;` to the element, all of the icons are bunched up to the right.
3. In the div with id **nav-home**, I have two nested divs with "columns" (classes) `col-sm-11`  and `col-sm-1`. the former is to hold an SVG object, and the latter is to display a 'control panel'. However, the section for the SVG is not displayed at all (or has width=0px) and the single column element issue is shown left-adjusted instead.

What is causing these issues and what is the solution?

Comment: I made a sandbox for the two first points of your question by using flexBox, Have a look
[menu template](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-montalcini-l2d81?file=/index.html)

Comment: @antoineso Thanks I have been able to identify and apply the change you made for the 2nd issue, but I can't identify what you did to fix issue 1 - and some of the changes like the **width being set to 30%** for `.dropbtn` seem counter-intuitive. Care to elaborate some more on fix for issue 1?

Comment: for the first issue i removed some div (the one with the cols-sm-3) because I think that bootstrap add margin between col.
The width of 30% is to avoid your navBar to wrap under the dropped down button on small screen.

Comment: @antoineso I see - but, I don't want to do that (removing the `col-sm-3` class from the div, because the it is no longer responsive).